# How Do I order by a date with date:time format, then order by non numeric variable

Tags: r

I would like to First order my.data by date thne by the non numeric account variable.  Forcing the same accounts together by date.  Example

```
My.data <- structure(list(Account = c("4Z123445", "2345678", "1234567","4Z123445"), dateofEntry = c("2015-06-07:03-16-43", "2015-07-27:02-12-02", "2015-06-21:01-56-15", "2015-07-06:18-04-30"),
                      Message = c("Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail")),
                      .Names = c("Account", "dateofEntry", "Message" ), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

My.data
Account    dateofEntry           Message
4Z123445   2015-06-07:03-16-43   Pass
2345678    2015-07-27:02-12-02   Fail
1234567    2015-06-21:01-56-15   Pass
4Z123445   2015-07-06:18-04-30   Fail
```

Cleaned data would be something like:

```
My.data2
Account    dateofEntry           Message
1234567    2015-06-21:01-56-15   Pass
2345678    2015-07-27:02-12-02   Fail
4Z123445   2015-06-07:03-16-43   Pass  
4Z123445   2015-07-06:18-04-30   Fail
```

Comment: it looks like you want to order your data by `Account` and then `dateofEntry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question correctly the following code should do it:

```
My.data[order(My.data[,1], My.data[,2]),]
   Account         dateofEntry Message
3  1234567 2015-06-21:01-56-15    Pass
2  2345678 2015-07-27:02-12-02    Fail
1 4Z123445 2015-06-07:03-16-43    Pass
4 4Z123445 2015-07-06:18-04-30    Fail
```

Comment: Referring to columns by their number is in general bad practice.

Comment: Hey, @MichaelChririco appreciate the comment, still new around here. What is considered good practice then?

Comment: @MichaelChirico how would this be written if not by number?

Comment: `My.data[order(My.data$Account, My.data$dateofEntry),]`; it's longer but a) more robust and b) most IDEs (including RStudio) have tab completion-- so you can type `My.data$A`, hit `[Tab]`, and it will fill `Account` for you automatically.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is easy with `order` in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
> setDT(My.data)[order(Account,dateofEntry)]
    Account         dateofEntry Message
1:  1234567 2015-06-21:01-56-15    Pass
2:  2345678 2015-07-27:02-12-02    Fail
3: 4Z123445 2015-06-07:03-16-43    Pass
4: 4Z123445 2015-07-06:18-04-30    Fail
```

You can simply reverse the order if you really do want to sort by date first:

```
setDT(My.data)[order(dateofEntry,Account)]
    Account         dateofEntry Message
1: 4Z123445 2015-06-07:03-16-43    Pass
2:  1234567 2015-06-21:01-56-15    Pass
3: 4Z123445 2015-07-06:18-04-30    Fail
4:  2345678 2015-07-27:02-12-02    Fail
```

Comment: thank you.  I am moving from SAS to R and it's all quite new.  With self teaching.  You *all* on this forum have been great!

Comment: @AllyKat were especially happy to help converts! you'll get the hang of it soon enough :)

Comment: Here is a quick-start [cheatsheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/datatable.pdf) for `data.table`. If you're interested, here are some [starter's guides](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(My.data, Account, dateofEntry)
```